# how to apply animation when menu is being pushed

Tags: css, css-animations

I have 4 menu elements and next to them located languages, when i hover on languages they are moving from right to left and pushing menu. How to apply smooth animation effect for that pushing? Please check link below so you can understand clearly what i mean.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
                <span class="lang">
                <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
                </span>

      </ul>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes languageIn {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); opacity:0; }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); opacity:1; }

}

.navbar-nav a {
  line-height: 40px !important;
  position:relative;
}

.navbar-nav li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav li > a:active {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.navbar-nav a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff0000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.navbar-nav a:focus::after:not(.lang li a) {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a.active::after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff0000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.nav > li > a {
    padding:0px;
}
.nav li {
    padding-right:40px;
}

.lang li  {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  animation: goIn .5s ease-out;
}

 .lang li:not(:last-child) {
   display:none;
}

.lang:hover li:not(:last-child) {
  display:inline-block;
  animation: languageIn .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is full code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRzxmR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little, so now it will work.
It plays with the width, and uses transition instead of animation.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #222222;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

html,body {
  color: #191818;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Museo Sans Cyrl 100", sans-serif;
  animation: fadein 4.5s
  height: 100%;
}
/* Animate  on Loading page*/
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}



.navbar-default {
  z-index:99;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(248,248,248,.6);
}

.navbar-nav a {
  line-height: 40px !important;
  position:relative;
  /*top:20px;*/
}

.navbar-nav li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav li > a:active {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #ff0000 !important;
}


.navbar-nav a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff0000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.navbar-nav a:focus::after:not(.lang li a) {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a.active::after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ff0000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.navbar-nav .active {
  color: #ff0000 !important; 
}

.nav > li > a {
 padding:0px;
}
.nav li {
 padding-right:40px;
}

.logo-block {
  margin-left: 120px;
}
.logo-block h1 {
  color: #1b1a18;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.logo {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    float: left;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-palceholder {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.navbar-brand h5{
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 1px 0px 0px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-collapse{
  width: 100%;
}


/* PLACE WHERE LANGUAGE CONFIGURES */

.lang li  {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 7px;
  animation: goIn .5s ease-out;
}

 .lang li:not(:last-child) {
   transform: translateX(100%); opacity:0; width: 0;
   display: inline-block;
   transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.lang:hover li:not(:last-child) {
  transform: translateX(0); opacity:1; width: 2em;
}

.lang li a {
 color: #ff0000;
}
span.lang li {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}



/*nav fix*/
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.navbar-default {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
span.lang li {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.navbar-padding{
  padding: 15px 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>logo style</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 
<header id="header">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6">

     <div class="logo"></div>
     <h5>Logo<br> style</h5>
     <div class="clear"></div>

      </a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-padding" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ">
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
       <li><a class="active" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
    <span class="lang">
         <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">RU</a></li>
    </span>

      </ul>



    </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!--Container-->
</nav>
  
</header>





<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRGYNb